# Electron orbitals and the circular membrane vibrations

Tags: waves, atomic-physics

I just stumbled across the fascinating analogy between electron orbitals and the fundamental waves of a circular membrane in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).

Now the weird and arbitrary looking orbitals don't look so arbitrary any more.

The analogy has one obvious flaw though in that the vibrations in the circular membrane lack a dimension.

My question is whether there is another macroscopic analogy in three dimensions. Obvious ideas would be sound waves in either gas in a spherical containment or a vibrating spherical solid with an appropriately inflexible border.

I wonder whether this is even theoretically more close as an analogy to the electron orbitals and if it is, whether such waves occur in practice for some reason (maybe there's even an application for it, who knows).

(There is obviously another problem in the analogy that is independent from the lacking dimension, which is that there will probably always different amplitudes for sonic waves and no way to model the "spin", but that's that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect analogy would be one in which wave function satisfied by the vibrating system satisfies the exact same differential equation as the Coulomb-Schrödinger equation governing the shapes of atomic orbitals.

I can't think of any physical examples with an exact match.
But, it turns out that the angular part of the Schrödinger equation alone already qualitatively characterizes the shape of atomic orbitals closely.  In this case, any spherically vibrating object would do:

Take a look at this paper: http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Publications/Basketball.pdf
(figure 4)

Comment: According to the paper it's typically an exercise for undergraduates. :-) Thanks for the link.